# Conditionally turn off Bugsnag in Angular

Tags: angular, bugsnag

I am running Bugsnag in Angular 8.x and want to completely turn off reporting based on a property in environment.ts. I know how to pass the property, but I cannot figure out how to turn off reporting. What is the process for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a short look into Bugsnag docs for Angular:
https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/javascript/angular/

And found out that bugsnag is used as a provider:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [ { provide: ErrorHandler, useFactory: errorHandlerFactory } ]
})
```

I would change by adding an `if` where its possible to only add the provider for a specific environment:

```
const providers = [];

if (enviroment.production) {
  providers.push({ provide: ErrorHandler, useFactory: errorHandlerFactory });
}

@NgModule({
  providers,
})
```

Answer (score 1):

For the prosperity, I let the 'official' solution here - because building dynamic providers seems not working in module.app :

```js
Bugsnag.start({
  apiKey: '**YOURKEY***',
  enabledReleaseStages: ['production', 'staging'], // <=== Just enable for production and staging...
});
```

Here is the doc : https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/javascript/angular/configuration-options/#enabledreleasestages

Comment: How do you suggest it knows whether the current build is production or staging?